# How should I model a MongoDB database for managing a large number of contacts and their organizations

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have a database with 1 million contacts, and I anticipate it will grow to 2 million over the next 3 years. Users can organize contacts into lists based on organizations and apply multiple sorts and filters using different properties. For instance, a user might create an "Amazon" list containing 20,000 Amazon contacts and then apply additional filters for research purposes.

My question is: What is the best way to model this in MongoDB? Should I store the organization contact IDs as an array within the List model and filter this array when users apply filters? Alternatively, should I store the organization name and perform a single query that filters by organization name and other criteria? How do I decide which approach to take?